# Prevent adjust stock when removing product from an order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I'm trying to find a way to stop products going back in to stock when removing them from an order.

This is when we go in to the "Orders" screen, click on an individual order and remove a single product from that order. As standard it goes back in to stock.

I've been looking at the `wc_delete_order_item` function but can't seem to figure it out.

```php
function wc_delete_order_item( $item_id ) { 

    if ( ! $item_id = absint( $item_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    } 

    $data_store = WC_Data_Store::load( 'order-item' ); 

    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_delete_order_item', $item_id ); 

    $data_store->delete_order_item( $item_id ); 

    do_action( 'woocommerce_delete_order_item', $item_id ); 

    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, however before `wc_delete_order_item` we can find in `includes/class-wc-ajax.php`

```php
// Before deleting the item, adjust any stock values already reduced.
    if ( $item->is_type( 'line_item' ) ) {
        $changed_stock = wc_maybe_adjust_line_item_product_stock( $item, 0 );
```

The `wc_maybe_adjust_line_item_product_stock` function from `admin/wc-admin-functions.php` contains the following filter hook `woocommerce_prevent_adjust_line_item_product_stock`

---

So to answer your question, you could use (where the function can be further specified via the other parameters: only certain products, etc...)

```php
/**
 * Prevent adjust line item product stock.
 *
 * @since 3.7.1
 * @param bool $prevent If should prevent (false).
 * @param WC_Order_Item $item Item object.
 * @param int           $item_quantity Optional quantity to check against.
 */
function filter_woocommerce_prevent_adjust_line_item_product_stock ( $prevent, $item, $item_quantity ) {
    $prevent = true;

    return $prevent;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_adjust_line_item_product_stock', 'filter_woocommerce_prevent_adjust_line_item_product_stock', 10, 3 );
```

Or in short

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_adjust_line_item_product_stock', '__return_true' );
```